# How to avoid the Hudson/ClearCase error message "not a valid snapshot view path"?

Tags: hudson, clearcase

Though I am using Dynamic View in ClearCase, my Hudson is throwing below "`is not a valid snapshot view path.`" error message.

```
build] $ cmd.exe /C '"ant.bat -file build.xml -DCC_BASELINE_NAME=<baselinename> update-view && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: build.xml
update-view:
 [ccupdate] cleartool: Error: 'E:\Views\<view-tag>' is not a valid snapshot view path.

BUILD FAILED
: Failed executing: cleartool update -overwrite -ctime -log log.log E:/Views/<view-tag>
```

Please suggest me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a dynamic view, this is the expected message: ClearCase cannot "update" a dynamic view - this is for snapshot views only.

If you are using a snapshot view, then use the **full path** (instead of a [shortcut through the Windows command `subst`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/t_use_subst_cmd_win.htm))

The full path of a snapshot view should be:

```
C:\path\to\YourSnapshotView
```

In it, you should at least see one VOB folder, and subfolders.

`E:\Views` isn't the path to a snapshot view (it may be the path where several snapshot views are defined, but not just one)

---

The [ClearCase plugin for Hudson/Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin) can use either dynamic or snapshot views, but:

- You need to make sure you don't select options like load rules if your view tag is a dynamic view.
- Click the "Advanced" button to reveal the advanced options, including the dynamic view options.

[image: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/2916537/base_dynamic_config.png?version=1&modificationDate=1252688398000]

(If the slave is on Windows, you would put `M:\` instead of `/view`)

---

The [OP Karthik Was](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3963980/karthik-was) commented [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425463/how-to-avoid-the-hudson-clearcase-error-message-not-a-valid-snapshot-view-path/25426586?noredirect=1#comment39696852_25426586):

> First I have created a Snapshot view and then created a Dynamic View.
>   So, when I have created the Snapshot view a `View.dat` file has been generated; Hudson has identified the Snapshot view and passed that step.
>   Then I have created a Dynamic view created on `M:\`